# How to add additional fields in magento order report?

Tags: magento, report

In magento admin panel  `Sales->Orders` shows list of orders.
There is a option called `Export`. This only exports the column showing in orders grid.
I need to add more columns ( item names, attributes,discount price etc..) and I don't want to show these additional fields in grid.

How can I achieve this. For order CSV export , what file I need to edit?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

HI for this you can copy the file from

> app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php
>
> to
>
> app/code/core/local/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php

and in the new file you can add new functions like

```
protected function csvColumns() {
        $this->addColumn('real_order_id', array(
            'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Order ID'),
            'width' => '80px',
            'type'  => 'text',
            'index' => 'increment_id',
        ));

                $this->addColumn('store_id', array(
                    'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Purchased From (Store)'),
                    'index'     => 'store_id',
                    'type'      => 'store',
                    'store_view'=> true,
                    'display_deleted' => true,
                ));


            $this->addColumn('created_at', array(
                'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Order Date'),
                'index' => 'created_at',
                'type' => 'datetime',
                'width' => '100px',             
            ));
}
```

you can add as many as field in this which is in your sales table

and for xml export  you can add a one more function named as

```
protected function xmlColumns() { }
```

and same you can add as many as fields in this. these will just appear in your export not in your grid.

Let me know if there is any confusion.  thanks

Comment: Can you tell me is it working for you ? if yes than please mark the  answer as yes